# Dynamic iframe onload not firing?

Tags: jquery

I figure this is possible because there are a ton of similar questions (that have been solved) but none seem to deal with dynamically created iframes.

Basically I'm using jquery to create a temp iframe to load files (from a file path served through an ajax call) to then open a file download prompt.

Everything works but to keep my DOM from being populated by a bunch of iframes I would like the iframes to be removed once the file is downloaded.

My iframe creation code:

```
$('<iframe class="downloadIFrame" src="'+data['url']+'"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
```

And the code to destroy it (in the "ready" jquery event callback):

```
$('.downloadIFrame').live('load', function() { alert('loaded');$(this).remove(); });
```

I don't get the alert that the iframe was loaded so it's not called. Any clue?

Comment: where is the second code snippet located? it needs to be before the first snippet and/or outside of the .ready eventHandler.

Comment: the creation of the iframe is in a function outside of the .ready which is called from an onclick handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live` works on event bubbling mechanism where as `iframe` `load` event is not user action triggered. So you cannot use `live` to handle the `iframe` load event.

Also before setting the `src` of the iframe you should attach the `iframe` `load` event handler. This is to avoid the case when iframe gets loaded before the load event is attached.

Try this

```
$('<iframe class="downloadIFrame"></iframe>')
.appendTo('body')
.load(function(){
   $(this).remove();
}).attr("src", data['url']);
```

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned on margusholland's response, I think that the reason it's not triggering the onLoad is because the type of file being loaded in the iframe isn't text. The alert pops up when I download txt or html files but pngs fail. Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Hey - I disagree with your second statement. Unlike images, iFrames only get called when they are attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use a live listener.

```
$('<iframe class="downloadIFrame" src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
$('.downloadIFrame').load(function() { alert('loaded');$(this).remove(); });
```

Works fine for me in Webkit.

Comment: See I thought because I was creating my iframes dynamically that I would have to do it live. It still doesn't work but I have a feeling it should so I'm guessing it's because the response header isn't text/html but other things as well. I load pdfs and pngs and such, does it still work if you try to load a file that isn't html?

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the alert code in the dom of the iframe you've created - it has its own dom, thus its own event hierarchy etc.

Think of it as a totally separate page.

Comment: The iframe is used to open the files that I'm trying to download (since the files are served from an external server). So basically the iframe doesn't contain a webpage so I can't put it in there.