# Weird Captcha. How it works?

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies, captcha

I want to get an image captcha from https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/CaptchaGenerator.aspx.

I can not get it.

But if I open a new tab with url https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/default.aspx before I open https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/CaptchaGenerator.aspx, the image is shown.

I am just curious with https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/CaptchaGenerator.aspx. Why I can not open it if I have open https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/default.aspx yet.

I have tried this code but unfortunately i am failed. The image still not shown up.

```
<?php

//The curl_init() will initialize a new session and return a CURL handle.
//curl_exec($ch) This function should be called after you initialize a CURL session and     all the options for the session are set. Its purpose is simply to execute the predefined CURL session (given by the ch). 
//curl_setopt( $ch, option, value) Set an option for a CURL session identified by the ch parameter. option specifies which option to set, and value specifies the value for the option given.

$url = "https://agent.lionair.co.id/LionAirAgentsPortal/default.aspx"; // From URL to get webpage contents.
$cookie_file_path = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/curl-examples/cookieFolder/cook";

$ch = curl_init();  // Initialize a CURL session.
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  // Return Page contents.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  // Pass URL as parameter.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); // Tempat menaruh cookies.
$html = curl_exec($ch);  // grab URL and pass it to the variable.

$ch = curl_init();  // Initialize a CURL session.
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  // Return Page contents.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);  // Karena keluarannya gambar, maka di-    set binary = true.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://agent.lionair.co.id/LionAirAgentsPortal/CaptchaGenerator.aspx");  // Pass URL as parameter.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); // Tempat cookies di mana cookies mana yang mau digunakan.

$gambar = curl_exec($ch);  // grab URL and pass it to the variable.
curl_close($ch);  // close curl resource, and free up system resources.

?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://agent.lionair.co.id/LionAirAgentsPortal/default.aspx" name="form1" method="post">
        <label for="txtLoginName">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="txtLoginName" />
        <br/>
        <label for="txtPassword">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="txtPassword" />
        <br/>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $gambar; ?>" />
        <br/>
        <label for="CodeNumberTextBox">Captcha: </label>
        <input type="text" name="CodeNumberTextBox" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="otentikasi" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: yah, i think so. But you could try it by yourself in your browser. **First**, go to https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/CaptchaGenerator.aspx. It would not shown up anything. **Second**, go to https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/default.aspx and open new tab https://agent.lionair.co.id/lionairagentsportal/CaptchaGenerator.aspx. The image captcha would be there. :really curious:

Comment: I am sure it is definitely about cookie. But how I can showing image captcha up on my form ? It should be take a hard work to find it.

Answer (score 2):

The CAPTCHA generator is defining the CAPTCHA in a session, which is only getting defined by the actual page. This is a very standard practice to provide exactly one way to generate the CAPTCHA.

If the image generator were responsible for producing the CAPTCHA, then you would have a race condition where what is seen isn't necessarily the true CAPTCHA value before the page is submitted. Additionally, some developer tools like Firebug and Chrome's developer tools may load the image internally, which would update the CAPTCHA without the user's knowledge. It just leads to more confusion if the image generator creates the CAPTCHA value, too.

Comment: So, how i can get the image ? Because what I need is the image to be replaced in my form as seen on my code above. :'(

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Your code is already juggling the cookies received, so I can only guess they have hardened their CAPTCHA against server to server (non-human) requests by requiring JavaScript or something similar client-side.

Comment: Hi [jimp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/791265/jimp) I have deleted code that involved firebug. The image captcha is still not showing up. Tonight seems would be nightmare for me :'(

Comment: Yups, i see more bit complex javascript there. They are being named "validation", "validationGroup", "Page_ClientValidate", etc. You could see it at https://agent.lionair.co.id/LionAirAgentsPortal/WebResource.axd?d=kkSoclFaYs7QV6k2NSzg5pPlyMw2k8y-kPzxkj8fU4mySdFfmiFOCHnKrzd2ovETpI4HzxUhZPOg0OyboSo-RP3tPvE1&amp;t=634209029469717278

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent iframe on your page that will include default.aspx page. That way the server will think he needs to server the default.aspx page and will set the session cookie on the client. Later on when you'll try to access the CaptchaGenerator.aspx page you will get a response cause the session cookie will exists on the client cookie storage.

```
<iframe src ="https://agent.lionair.co.id/LionAirAgentsPortal/default.aspx" style="widht:0px;height:0px"/>
```

You'll maybe want to wait for the iframe to load and the cookie creation process is done before trying to include the image this could be done on client side using Java Script.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Very big really thanks, Uri. I will give it a try. I will report here if this way is works. Cheers !!!

Comment: I got problem when I waiting iframe event onLoad fired. I use load() function in jquery but it is not fired at all. And I use ready() function but the it is fired before iframe is loaded.

Comment: @GangsarSwaPurba I think you can find a solution in the following answer: [dynamic-iframe-onload-not-firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285809/dynamic-iframe-onload-not-firing) Long live stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy..
Add this code :

> $ImageCaptcha=base64_encode($gambar);

after "$gambar = curl_exec($ch);"

and then change your code : echo $gambar; 
with

> echo $ImageCaptcha;

Answer (score 0):

change: 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);`

with this one:
`$cookie="ASP.NET_SessionId="."$cookieValue";`
change with `($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookie);`

it works for me, but u need an effort to get cookievalue before on $url
Hope this helpfull..